# Friend function can't access class variables

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend

I thought that friend functions could access class variables as in how I try to do v.x, v.y, v.z in the << function. But it doesn't compile. It says it's unable to resolve identifier at those lines.

Also I'm trying to learn how to use namespaces. Even though I use the namespace vec in the implementation file I still have to include Vector:: before everything so what's the point?

Header file:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

namespace vec {

    class Vector {
    private:
        double x, y, z;

    public:
        Vector(double, double, double);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,  const Vector&);

    };

}

#endif  /* VECTOR_H */
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "Vector.h"
#include <iostream> 
using namespace vec;

//Constructor
Vector::Vector(double x1 = 0, double y1 = 0, double z1 = 0) {
    x = x1;
    y = y1;
    z = z1;
}

//Operators
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Vector& v) {
    out<<"<"<<v.x<<", "<<v.y<<", "<<v.z<<">";
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Your function definition is `Vector::operator<<`; it should be `operator<<`...

Answer (score 4):

Friend functions aren't member functions, and `operator<<` needs to not be a member in order to have a left side of `ostream`. Change it to a free function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Vector v) {
              ^^ no qualification
```

I would also take the vector by const reference instead of by value.

Comment: @billz, Soon, yes. I noticed not long ago that I was close :)

Comment: I changed the function to this|   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Vector& v) {   | But it made no difference, I still have the same error.

Comment: @user1884814, Change the second parameter to `const Vector &` because it isn't being modified, and make sure you change it in the declaration and definition.

Comment: I've added the changes I made to the original post, still no difference. Let me know if you can see why it can't access the variables x, y, z in the header file if you can.

Comment: Please, I still need help.

Comment: What exactly are the errors you are getting? Please add the compiler error output to the question itself, that will definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend function belongs to the namespace vec and must be defined as such.

Change it to:

```
std::ostream &vec::operator << (std::ostream &out , const Vector &v) { //etc
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the namespace. Easy enough to just wrap the cpp file in a `namespace vec {...}`